# ModelCheckpoint - save_best_only=True

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I need explanation of save best only option of ModelCheckpoint. If I have a code like this

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
cp = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path+"/model-lstmMulti", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)]        
history_callback = model.fit(X, y, epochs=350, verbose=1, callbacks=cp)
```

and then I want to see the accuracy of that best model:

```
acc_history = history_callback.history["acc"]
np.savetxt(path+"/acc_history.txt", np.asarray(acc_history))
```

I got the array ie. accuracy of the models of all epochs. Why I don't get only one value - accuracy of the best model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelCheckpoint` is a callback function used to save model file (h5) after epochs. It doesn't affect the return history of `fit()` method. Just use `np.max` to get the best acc from acc history will do your job.

Comment: Thank you on your explanation. I tried

    score = model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=1)

it gave me:
    Test accuracy: 0.9047109207708779

and

    print(np.max(history_callback.history["acc"]))

gave me:
0.9561027837259101

Comment: On a smaller dataset I got the same accuracy:
model.evaluate Test accuracy: 0.9896551724137931
 np.max: 0.9896551724137931

Comment: I guess you do `model.evaluate` right after `model.fit`, this will use the latest model to do prediction. You need to do `model.load_weights("path to your best model")` before prediction to get best acc. @MarioZ

Comment: `ModelCheckPoint` should save your best model. I suggest to specify the `filepath` in `ModelCheckPoint` so that you can get the best model by simply look at file name. It could be something like `ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path+"/ep{epoch:03d} loss{loss:.3f}.h5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)`

Comment: Why ModelCheckpoint do not save model on filepath? I noticed that when I tried to load_weights() according to your instructions.

Comment: @MarioZ It should save, please make sure you are giving a valid filepath for `ModelCheckPoint`. The model file should end with `.h5`

Comment: I tried to simplified path but not getting results nor even error on the modelcheckpoint line.

Comment: @MarioZ Could you just show your `ModelCheckPoint` line?

Comment: Ok. Finally I got the ModelCheckPoint saved with  cp = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/home/mario/modelLstmMulti.h5", monitor='acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)]

then I compile:
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
then I:
 model.load_weights("/home/mario/modelLstmMulti.h5")
Finally I got the accuracy:
0.9827586206896551
with
 score = model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=1)
 print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
and with:
 print(np.max(history_callback.history["acc"]))
I got pretty the same:
0.9896551724137931